# Ros2 for Unity create custom msg

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to add a custom msg to my **ROS2 for Unity** on Windows. From what I understand, I need to follow [this](https://github.com/RobotecAI/ros2cs/blob/master/README-WINDOWS.md#prerequisites). Everything is fine till I arrive at the point of modifying the `custom_messages.repos` file in order to get my custom msg from `get_repos.ps1`.

I **don't know how to write this file** in fact, it requires some URL and [other parameters](https://github.com/RobotecAI/ros2cs/blob/master/custom_messages.repos). But in my case, I don't have an online repo because as said [here](https://github.com/RobotecAI/ros2cs), I should put my *custom msg pkg* into `src/ros2` *sub-folder*. Obviously every time I run the `build.ps1`, I encountered some errors related to my msg.

After building ros2-for-Unity pkg and importing it into the project, I get this error in Unity: **error CS1061**: 'Teleop' does not contain a definition for 'ang' and no accessible extension method 'ang' accepting a first argument of type 'Teleop' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Remember that **ros2-for-unity is a plugin** so I can't do `ros2 topic list` from it. To see if the topic is active I need to launch the command from the normal `ros2_ws`, and I can see my msg sent correctly.

This is my custom msg that builds in the normal ws:

```
std_msgs/Header         header
# current position
geometry_msgs/Vector3[2]      pose        # meters
# current angles 
geometry_msgs/Vector3[2]   ang    # rad
```

This is my Unity subscriber:

```
namespace ROS2 {
 public class RCM2Omni : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ROS2UnityComponent ros2Unity;
        private ROS2Node ros2Node;
        private ISubscription<my_msgs.msg.Teleop> Omni2;
        private float[] transformations = new float[3];
        bool moving = false;

        void Start()
        {
            ros2Unity = GetComponent<ROS2UnityComponent>();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (ros2Node == null && ros2Unity.Ok())
            {
                ros2Node = ros2Unity.CreateNode("RCM2Omni");
             
                Omni2 = ros2Node.CreateSubscription<my_msgs.msg.Teleop>(
                  "/Teleop", msg => { parse(msg); });
            }

            if (moving)
            {              
                transform.Rotate(transformations[0], 0, 0);
                moving = false;
            }
        }

        public void parse(my_msgs.msg.Teleop msg)
        {
            transformations[0] = (float)msg.ang[1].x;
            moving = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone already had this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403535/ros2-for-unity-create-custom-msg/) by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2022-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-11**:
Is the line with `transformations[0] = (float)msg.ang[1].x;` in the `parse(my_msgs.msg.Teleop msg)` correct? In the examples I can see

```
chatter_sub = ros2Node.CreateSubscription<std_msgs.msg.String>("chatter", msg => Debug.Log("Unity listener heard: [" + msg.Data + "]"));
```

so maybe try `msg.Data.ang[1]` or similar?

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-07-11**:
Even with `msg.Data` I receive: *'Teleop' does not contain a definition for 'Data' ..*
Instead, with only `msg`, I get the result in the console, but it's only the msg object, and I don't know if it has the elements or how to access it.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-11**:
I think you can check it from ground up - I would start with this example: https://github.com/RobotecAI/ros2cs/blob/master/src/ros2cs/ros2cs_examples/ROS2Listener.cs, check if it works with `std_msgs.msg.String`, then add your custom message and check with this simplest possible ROS 2 Listener if your message is heard correctly. I don't see e.g. `Ros2cs.Init();` in your code, that is there in the example listener code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution, in this answer I will resume all the steps I followed in one place.
First, to build your **Ros2-for-Unity** plugin follow [this](https://github.com/RobotecAI/ros2-for-unity/blob/master/README-WINDOWS.md#build-troubleshooting).

1. clone the repo
2. do `.\pull_repositories.ps1`, this will create the ros2cs folder
3. open the **ros2cs folder**, and create the **custom_messages** folder in it. This is not mandatory, it should work if you put it in ros2cs/ros2, but I didn't test it.
4. add my **custom_msg_pkg** in that folder *exactly as it is in the ros2ws*
5. do `./build.ps1 -standalone`
6. do `create_unity_package.ps1`
7. Now **in Unity**, do Assets->Import package->Custom package and select your newly created UnityPackage. Import all.
8. Write publisher and subscriber, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UklzwBuu1o&list=PL-2lSApPLd9Z57Pt8Mij1ypgJ8xYPLCdW&index=5).

And then final but a **most important reminder**, if you'll ever face this error *in Unity*: **error CS1061**: `your_msg` does not contain a definition for `your_field` and no accessible extension method `your_field` accepting a first argument of type `your_msg` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**CHECK THAT THE FIRST LETTER OF THE ELEMENT IS CAPITAL**.

For example: to access `std_msgs.String.data` in **C++** you do `msg.data`, but in **C#** (or Unity, I don't know which one complains) you must do `msg.Data` (capital D !), or you will have **error CS1061**. The same goes for your `custom_msg` fields! I want to highlight this because it made me cry for 2 days and it's a very silly error.

Also thanks to @ljaniec for the help!

---

Originally posted by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) with karma: 100 on 2022-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2